# Adding picture to merged Excel cell based on a cell value

Tags: excel, image, dynamic

I have an Excel Workbook with a worksheet named Image. In the worksheet, I have merged a number of cells together to create a larger cell and have a separate cell that contains a number, let's say the number 5. The merged cells and separate cell is repeated 7 more times in the worksheet.  What I need to do is to use the number in the separate cell and concatenate that into the file path to produce a full path name for the image (such as "C:\temp\5\image.png"). The image is then loaded from the file path into the associated merged cells.  I've scoured the web for a couple of days to figure this out but VBA and Excel are not my strong points.  Any help is appreciated.

Update: This is what I've been able to figure out so far.  When I hard code the imageName path, it works just fine. However I would like to be able to use it like =PictureLookupUDF(A1, H17) where the number located in the cell A1 is used to define the image path.  Any ideas?

```
    Public Function PictureLookupUDF(folderID As Range, Location As Range)
        Dim lookupPicture As Shape
        Dim sheetName As String
        Dim fileFolder As String
        Dim imageName As String
        fileFolder = Range(folderID)
        imageName = "C:\temp\AutoCompMap\" & fileFolder & "\Maps\AerialImagery2020Layout.png"
        sheetName = Location.Parent.Name
        'Add the picture in the right location
        Set insertPicture = Sheets(sheetName).Shapes.AddPicture _
(imageName, msoFalse, msoTrue, Location.Left, Location.Top, -1, -1)
        insertPicture.Width = insertPicture.Width * 1.185
        insertPicture.Height = insertPicture.Height * 1.185

        End Function
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you have so far?

Comment: I don't have any code so far.

Comment: This is what I've been able to figure out so far.  When I hard code the imageName path, it works just fine. However I would like to be able to use it like =PictureLookupUDF(A1, H17) where the number located in the cell A1 is used to define the image path.  Any ideas?

Comment: You do know we don't know what your document looks like? What is the hard coded path you used (the one that works) and what is the value or `fileFolder` and the resulting value of `imageName`? Did you compare the value of `imageName` to the actual file path?

Comment: Yes I know that you don't know what the whole document looks like.  I can't share that which is why I've added as much detail as allowed.  The hard coded path that worked was:imageName = "C:\temp\AutoCompMap\165\Maps\AerialImagery2020Layout.png". The "165" is the value that needs to be inserted from cell A1.